# Backbones and subnets

Tags: subnet

I need some assistance with an assignment I'm doing for college. I think it's pretty easy, but I might be missing something.

The task is to create a network based on the given plan [(click here to see it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JOcT.png). So I've got all the machines (virtual, of course), but somehow I can't get the settings right. For example Client_A, cannot connect to Server_A even though they are on the same subnet (I guess).

Here are the settings:
Server_A: IP-172.25.150.1; Mask-255.255.255.0; Gateway-10.0.2.2.
Client_A: IP-172.25.150.2; Mask-255.255.255.0; Gateway-10.0.2.2.
Server_B: IP-172.25.151.1; Mask-255.255.255.0; Gateway-10.0.2.2.
Client_B: IP-172.25.151.2; Mask-255.255.255.0; Gateway-10.0.2.2.
(10.0.2.2 is the VirtualBox "router").

I've tried to Ping Server_A from Client_A and the other way round, but all I get "Host not reachable".

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1):

I guarantee this question is going to get flagged, but I'll help you anyway

Server A and Server B are not in the same subnet. Your masks are /24 which denotes that Server A is in 172.25.150.0/24 and Server B is in 172.25.151.0/24. They're separate.

Your gateways are inaccessible because they're outside of your networks. If you can't access your gateway you won't be able to get to the other subnets.

Comment: Well, ok.  So I put Server A and Server B on the same subnet (let's say 172.25.150.1/24 and 172.25.150.2/24). Now how can I can Client A and Server A on the same sub-subnetwork?

Comment: Sorry I misread the question about your Clients and assumed you were trying to talk between subnets, rather than A->A and B->B. In VirtualBox your VMs have a setting under the Network tab. What is it set to?

Comment: can you define what you mean by "sub-subnetwork"? A "network" in this context simply means a broadcast domain. Everything in the broadcast domain should be able to communicate with or without a gateway (simply because all you need is for ARP to complete to hit anything else on the broadcast domain in order to pass traffic from device to device).

Comment: VirtualBox network setting is the default NAT. 

Just make clear - I need two subnets:
**Subnet A** with _Server A_ and _Client A_ in it;
**Subnet B** with _Server B_ and _Client B_ in it.

It also must be possible for _Client A_ to reach _Client B_ (e.g. ping it succesfully)

Comment: In order to leave a network you must be able to reach a gateway (eg, gateway must be on same network as clients). In order to hit a specific network on the other side of your gateway, your gateway must have a route to that network (eg, it will need to know how to reach the gateway for the second subnet).